# <select> change <option> to a comma

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Simply select/option code I need to change option as comma. Eg

```
<select>
<option>select 1</option>
<option> select 2</option>
</select>
```

I need change  to a comma so code would look like

```
<select>
Select 1, Select 2
</select>
```

What is important I need this code in HTML

Comment: Why would you want such a bizarre thing?

Comment: Your explanation of what you need is really poor. Could you elaborate it a little bit better? And yeah, why would you want such a bizarre thing, indeed.

Comment: Select1, Select2 is what I receive from database (Gravity View) and I need to put it in drop down menu select.

Comment: So maybe try to explode this data intro array elements first before rendering them? If I understood you well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I understand that you just want to create the menu items from the comma separated string that you received from your database. This can be done with plain javascript like this:

```js
var options = "Select 1, Select 2";
var select = document.getElementById("list");
var options = options.split(",");
for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){  
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = options[i];
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id="list"></select>
```

Comment: Theodore K.You are life saver;) Thanks mate it works great:) It didn't because Gravity View Add "br /" on all lines but deleted them and it is great:)

Comment: @Paweł Wiórko, Great! Please though, improve your question in order to help future users. Add there what you wrote in the comments too.

Answer (score 2):

you can not change the html select element structure to words separated by comma.

in Html5 the select element's options are

> The list of options for a select element consists of all the option element children of the select element, and all the option element children of all the optgroup element children of the select element, in tree order.

[The select element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element)